# Describe geometrically what the vector signifies.

Tags: linear-algebra

> What is the geometric description of $B = \text{span} \space \{[1, 1], [2, 6], [3, 5]\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, where $[x, y]$ is a vector.

So $B = a[1, 1] + b[2, 6] + c[3, 5], a, b , c \in \mathbb{R}$

Is there a way to simply this further so I can get the geometric description?

Comment: What do you mean by geometric description? Are the vectors linearly dependent or not?

Comment: Perhaps an easier question might be: are there any vectors in $\mathbb R^2$ that are not in $B$?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you know that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a vector space of dimension $2$ and this means (by definition of **dimension** of a vector space) that a basis in $\mathbb{R}^2$ contains at most two linearly independent vectors. Or, in other words that $\mathbb{R}^2$ the span of a couple of linearly independent vectors.

Now note that $\vec v=[1,1]$ and $\vec u= [2,6]$ are linearly independent, and, as a consequnce the span of these two vectors  is $\mathbb{R}^2$ and, in particular, $\vec w[3,5]=2[1,1]+\frac{1}{2}[2,6]$ is a linear combination of $\vec v$ and $\vec u$.

So the ''geometric description'' of  $B$ is the whole $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: For linear independence you need a set of vectors right?

Comment: You can see the definition of linear independence of a set of vectors here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence

Answer (score 0):

Can I offer a suggestion?  If you have a pair of perpendicular vectors, e.g.,

[ 3 , 5 ]  and [ 5 , -3 ]  then don't these offer an alternative x-y axis set (basis set)?  What is the span of any such two vectors?

Looking at the given 3 vectors, can you combine any two of them (by vector add or subtract) into a resultant vector perpendicular to the other vector?

Comment: For 2 vectors to span $R^2$ they need not be perpendicular.